# How do I make a fuel annotation for a templated function?

Tags: dafny

I would like to write Dafny some code with fuel annotations, like the following:

```
predicate {:fuel 0,0} eq<A>(x: A, y: A) 
{
  x == y
}

lemma {:fuel eq,1,2} reflexive<A>(x: A)
ensures eq(x, x)
{
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error message:

```
templates.dfy(6,13): Error: type '?' to the predicate 'eq' is not determined
templates.dfy(6,13): Error: the type of this expression is underspecified
```

Well, it looks like I just need to specify the type argument to eq. But the 'obvious' approach doesn't work. This code,

```
predicate {:fuel 0,0} eq<A>(x: A, y: A) 
{
  x == y
}

lemma {:fuel eq<A>,1,2} reflexive<A>(x: A)
ensures eq(x, x)
{
}
```

gives the error message:

```
templates.dfy(6,17): Error: this operator chain cannot continue with a descending operator
templates.dfy(6,18): Error: invalid UnaryExpression
```

It is possible to accomplish fuel annotations with templated functions in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

The "obvious" way to do it is indeed the way to do it. The parsing error messages you're getting were fixed in Dafny version 2.2.0 (more precisely, in a [10 July 2018 commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/commit/25ce07d748eba81802cb286eb41de182f0f5e704)).